# Windows 10 not passing variable to default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, windows-server-2016

So I keep getting the below error ONLY on Windows 10/Server 16 on this program.

[image]

The program code we've been using and is currently using in our production is:

```
  "let passdial = "http://192.168.6.21/call?auth=0d75f857-9ecc-45de-8e1a-a5593f41c56f&extension="& _USERID &"&number=" & phone_main & "0000000000"
  DOCUMENT "open", "http://www.mktresponse.com/clients/AutoDialerTest/default.aspx?Information="&passdial"
```

It works correctly in all the older OSes pre Win 10. So I'm confused as to why it's seeing it as a combined file path instead of passing the passdial variable to the default.aspx?

To me, it looks like Windows 10 doesn't know to handle the passing of the variable with that syntax.

Is there a code library missing or software update that I need to install?

Comment: Read IIS log files to see what status/sub status code you hit, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: If you application is web application so the point any browser not in windows, please try use different browsers and see the result

Comment: @LexLi- IIS logs don't show any error codes. Just the normal GET and POST commands per norm.

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem, it does the same thing in any browser. However, If I was to type that error string in a browser, it runs as it should. Which to me, points the issue to the way Windows is handling the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess -- and I don't know anything about superscript, but DOCUMENT "open" biglongurl smells to me like windows is trying to run your URL directly (so it will open in the default browser) and having a problem.

I would try escaping your URL, so

http://192.168.6.21/call?auth=0d75f857-9ecc-45de-8e1a-a5593f41c56f&extension=70121&number=20255512120000000000

will become:

http%3A%2F%2F192.168.6.21%2Fcall%3Fauth%3D0d75f857-9ecc-45de-8e1a-a5593f41c56f%26extension%3D70121%26number%3D20255512120000000000

There are myriad ways to accomplish this, check the Super-Scripting documentation on escaping URLs, or you can use something like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

To try this out, run super-script and change your open command to:

```
let passdial = "http%3A%2F%2F192.168.6.21%2Fcall%3Fauth%3D0d75f857-9ecc-45de-8e1a-a5593f41c56f%26extension%3D70121%26number%3D20255512120000000000"
  DOCUMENT "open", "http://www.mktresponse.com/clients/AutoDialerTest/default.aspx?Information="&passdial"
```

Comment: @weloytty- did you mean to leave the trailing double quotes at the end of passdial?

Comment: @weloytty- so it still errorred out. Arggh, so annoying. I found an article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4467268/url-encoded-unc-paths-not-url-decoded-in-windows-10-version-1803-later
But I can't fully make sense of it to create the proper syntax...not sure if it'll make more sense to you or someone else.